# Find the 2 values of array if i try to add them the result is specify number

Tags: javascript

Let me say, i have an array

```
var arr = [5,4,7,-3,-6,1,9,2]
```

Find the 2 value of array if i add that value the result is 11.

```
var result = 11
```

And the output become a new object are looked like this:

```
Output: {[4,7],[2,9]}
```

Can you explain what method to get this output?

Comment: How is this `{[4,7],[2,9]}` possible?

Comment: This is a very common problem that you can google, and this question doesn't really contain any specific questions or problems—just "how do I do it" :/

Comment: That's why ask. Did you understand the ouput sir? 4 + 7 = 11, 2+9 =11, so those items should added in ot new object

Comment: @rikiyudha This `{[4,7],[2,9]}` is not possible in javascript ❗

Comment: I have googling many times, and i don't find the correct method yet. And i just think should i make those array into a new array array that contain the combination of 2 value of those array?

Comment: Can you explain why those not possible? @Manas Khandelwal

Comment: @rikiyudha That is how javascript works! Objects need a key for each value! You can not store arrays like that in an object!

Comment: Ok. I understand. Then how if not using an object? How about two dimensional array?

Comment: @rikiyudha Yes, that is possible with a 2d array! Like this: `[[4,7],[2,9]]`

Comment: Can you explain? How its work?

Comment: @rikiyudha Always use `@` to tag people it sends notification.... Like `@rikiyudha`

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal OK. thanks for the reminder. can you explain me? how its works?

Comment: @rikiyudha I am adding the answer!

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this you need to use double loops. Like this,

```js
const arr = [5, 4, 7, -3, -6, 1, 9, 2];
const result = 11;
const output = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (i !== j && arr[i] + arr[j] === result) output.push([arr[i], arr[j]]);
  }
}

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; } /* Ignore this, Just for styling */
```

Comment: Thank You so much